# Writing orchestration by c#

Tags: c#, biztalk

I was wondering if there is any way to create/modify an orchestration by code instead of drawing the boxes.
I know that everything gets converted to c# code(or something very similar) in the .odx file. So is there a way to modify that code and have biztalk generate those drawings instead?

Since my experience is much more in C/C#, the code approach is much more natural to me than drawing approach.

BTW, I am NOT talking about writing custom pipelines or other external classes to be called from the orchestration, I already know how to do this. I really want to code the orchestration itself by code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While in theory this is possible I think I would rather gouge my own eyes out than try to write an orchestration by hand. The odx file is in two parts, the xml defines the shapes and layout and the xlangs code defines the types and functions describing the shapes. This a similar concept to the old "code behind" in aspx 1.1.

These two things are useless without each other, so the XML by itself will layout all the shapes but will not compile, and the code by itself cannot compile either (although to be honest I have never tried this).

If you are looking for a more standardised language to describe business processes you could look at BPEL, which is supported by BizTalk, but then again I have never worked with this so could not comment further.

Comment: The XML is in fact useless, it only contains shape names and positions. The XML can be generated from a plain XLang file using XSharpP.exe -tokenparse. (only problem with that is that you'll get an orchestration with meaningless shape names when viewing it in the orchestration debugger)

Comment: Thanks for that - this is obviously advanced stuff. Do you know if anyone actually uses these features?

Comment: Not as far as I know. I sometimes use it to quickly start a new orchestration following an existing pattern. But it's mostly information that would be useful to write visual studio extensions to facilitate directly editing XLang code (intellisense, syntax highlighting...).

Comment: thanks for the info, I will look into XSharpP.exe, I might actually be the first to actually use these features.

Answer (score 4):

In theory, orchestrations can be written using the XLang language

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577463(BTS.70).aspx

Whatever you create in the designer, it gets translated to XLang and then XLang is translated to C#. This also means that the code could probably be even written in C#, however, as I've tried to decompile the code once or twice - it's just too complicated.